# ListView doesn't fire selectionchanged

Tags: javascript, dom-events, windows-8.1, winjs

My HTML:

```
<div id="listViewBoxOffice" 
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"  
     data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: select('#movieThumbnailTpl'), selectionMode: 'single' }">
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.
    ready: function (element, options) {
        api.getBoxOffice().done(this.boxOffice, this.errBoxOffice);

        listViewBoxOffice.winControl.addEventListener('selectionchanging', this.selectionchanging);
        listViewBoxOffice.winControl.addEventListener('selectionchanged', this.selectionchanged);

    },
    boxOffice: function (movies) {
        var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(movies);
        listViewBoxOffice.winControl.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;
    },
    errBoxOffice: function (err) {
        debugger;
    },
    selectionchanged: function (evt) {
        console.log('changed');
    },
    selectionchanging: function (evt) {
        console.log('changing');
    }
});
```

My problem:

The event `selectionchanged` is never fired. The event `selectionchanging` is fired but with bad value in `newSelection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the documentation isn't as clear about this as I think it should be, you'll need to set the `tapBehavior` property to `"toggleSelect"` so that an item is fully selected. By default, the behavior is `invokeOnly` and with that it doesn't fully select the item. It clicks, but isn't selected.

There's a decent example located in the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211852.aspx).

If you store off a copy of the `listViewBoxOffice` instance, then from the events, you can get the current list via a promise:

```
listViewBoxOffice.selection.getItems().done(function(items) {
    // do something with the items...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To check wheather the selectionchanged event is working or not Right click on the listview item.I think when we just only click on the listview item it needs iteminvoke event and for selection we need to right click on the item.
Following is the code snipet which is firing the selectionchanged event

```
 <div id="UserListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" style="border-top: 5px solid #000; min-width:500px;" 
           data-win-options="{
                               selectionMode:'multi',
                               itemTemplate:select('#itemsList'),
                               layout:{    
                               type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}"
         > 

    </div>
```

and in the js

```
 UserListView.addEventListener("selectionchanged", selection);

function selection(evt) {
        var test = "testing";


    }
```

set the breakpoint and you can check in the evt the type="selectionchanged"

Answer (score 0):

please try using Item invoked. Here's the Msdn link
[Item invoked Winjs Listview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211827.aspx)

And try changing the selection accordingly.
Also if this does not work or you want selection changed only then Please post in the Template that you have designed. Will need to go through the entire code :)